Where is `str` class functions' source code being implemented?
Example of str in builtins.py
Hello everyone, I've just stopped at the Python source code of str class and I see a few str functions, such as capitalize and encode. However, there is no implementation there.
Thus, could anyone point me out where are those methods being implemented in Python? I have heard that they are implemented in Python's interpreter, but I can't find it anywhere.
Thanks for helping me!
I have tried to see where str class functions such as capitalize and encode being implemented.

The implementation is C; there is no native Python implementation at all. See f/e https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ef172521a9e9dfadebe57d590bfb53a0e9ac3a0b/Objects/stringlib/ctype.h#L95 for capitalize

(Also, note that requests for links to or recommendations for off-site resources are categorically off-topic)
